# Python "Int object is not iterable" during variable unpacking in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

I have a recursive function that moves through a binary tree and calculates the difference between the most left node and the most right one.

It does this by taking an argument "count" that is count-1 if I navigate to the left child and count+1 if I go to the right one.

It returns a tuple (countsx, countdx) where countsx (countdx) is the minimum (maximum) between the current count variable (for both countsx and countdx), the countsx (countdx) value returned by the left child and che countsx (countdx) value returned from the right child.

This is the code. It raises an error "Int type is not iterable" on the marked line at the beginning of the recursion.

```
def ausilioes17(tree, count):

    countsx = 0
    countdx = 0

    # If it's a leaf, just return the count parameter
    if not tree.sx and not tree.dx: return count

    if tree.sx:
        # it raises an error here when unpacking
        countsx, dummydx = ausilioes17(tree.sx, count-1) # <-------

    if tree.dx:
        dummysx, countdx = ausilioes17(tree.dx, count+1)

    return min(countsx, dummysx, count), max(countdx, dummydx, count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Tree() # has just left child (a.sx) and right child (a.dx)
    sx, dx = ausilioes17(a, 0)
    print(str(dx-sx))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tree is initially empty, so you're hitting `return count`, which cannot be unpacked into two values

Perhaps you wanted `return count, count`?